# Can I run Pitest on only 2 test files (no mutations found issue)?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, testing, mutation-testing, pitest

So I'm having issues with the following error when running Pitest "Skipping coverage and analysis as no mutations found". The advice I've seen so far seems to be editing the maven or gradle files, but I don't know/use maven or gradle.

All I have is a project in eclipse with the necessary libraries, and 2 lone test files that test the included jfreechart library. Both files run 100% passes on junit so that isn't an issue. Is there any way to resolve this problem? I feel like there's some stupid I'm getting wrong but I can't find any relevant information for my case.

Any help *really* appreciated

Comment: How are you running this "pitest" thing *now* if not through a build tool? How are you supplying it options? You're leaving a lot of information out, like what this has to do with Eclipse.

Comment: The issue is its not running. So I'm assuming I need to use a build tool like maven or gradle.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you are running pitest, but it will not mutate code in dependencies, only code defined within your project.

If you wish to mutate jfreechart you will need to the code from

https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart

The project looks to be built with maven, so you can configure pitest by following the documentation at

https://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/